# Sum of sides of a quadrilateral and sum of its diagonals

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, alternative-proof, geometric-inequalities

[image: A quadrilateral ABCD with diagonals AC and BC meeting at O]

A proposition says that the sum of the sides of a quadrilateral is greater than the sum of its diagonals. The proof for this proposition goes as follows:-

In quadrilateral $\mathrm{ABCD,}$
we have in $\Delta$$\mathrm{ACD,}$
$\mathrm{AC<AD+CD⋯(1)}$

Similarly,

In $\Delta$$\mathrm{ACB,}$

$\mathrm{AC<AB+CB⋯(2)}$

In $\Delta$$\mathrm{BCD,}$

$\mathrm{BD<BC+CD⋯(3)}$

and, in $\Delta$$\mathrm{ADB,}$

$\mathrm{BD<AD+AB⋯(4)}$

Hence, on adding all the equations, we achieve

$\mathrm{2(AB+BC+CD+AD)>2(AC+BD)}$

i.e., $\mathrm{AB+BC+CD+DA>AC+BD.}$

This proves our proposition well and good but out of nowhere I got stuck on an another seemingly strange but obvious thought process that should be an another proof to the proposition but somehow I guess I missed something important in the proof that contradicts the final results. Described below is the same deficient proof I am stuck upon.

In the same quadrilateral $\mathrm{ABCD,}$ diagonals $\mathrm{AC}$ and $\mathrm{BD}$ meet each other at $\mathrm{O.}$ Hence, they form the triangles $\mathrm{AOD , AOB , BOC}$ and $\mathrm{DOC.}$

Thence, on applying the triangle inequalities in the above triangles, we get

In $\Delta$$\mathrm{AOD}$, we have
$\mathrm{AO + OD > AD...(i)}$

In $\Delta$$\mathrm{AOB}$, we have
$\mathrm{AO + BO > AB...(ii)}$

In $\Delta$$\mathrm{BOC}$, we have
$\mathrm{BO + CO > BC...(iii)}$ and,

In $\Delta$$\mathrm{DOC}$, we have
$\mathrm{DO + CO > DC...(iv)}$

Finally, on adding the equations (i),(ii),(iii) and (iv), we get

$\mathrm{AO + OD + AO + BO + BO + CO + DO + CO > AB +AD + BC + DC}$

$\mathrm{= 2(AC + BD) > AB + AD + BC + DC}$
$$\mathrm{= AC + BD > \frac{AB + AD + BC + DC}{2}}$$

The conclusion of the proof is however incorrect and so, somewhere in the proof I think I have blundered.
To whomsoever it may concern, please help me with where did I go wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing *wrong* with your arguements. It just proves a completely different result.

---

Let the sum of the sides be $x$ and the sum of the diagonals be $y$.
The first proof shows that $x>y$, your  workings show that $y>\frac{x}{2}.$
Therefore,
$$x>y>\frac{x}{2}$$
which essentially bounds (lower and upper) the sum of diagonals.

Comment: (And in fact the bounds are tight, as the examples of a long thin rectangle and a long thin rhombus show)